# How to give minute in fixedDelay & initialDelay in @scheduled spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I am new for scheduler in spring. I read so many articles on @schedule but in every example they gave time in seconds and milliseconds.

Problem Statement : As per my requirement, after my program start my scheduler will start after 15 minutes  (initial Delay ) and then it executes the task every after 5 minutes (FixedRate) . To achieve this how can I give time in minutes is their any best way to achieve this problem ?

Code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledConfiguration {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000, initialDelay = 900000)
    public void scheduleFixedRateWithInitialDelayTask() {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println("Fixed rate task with one second initial delay - " + now);
    }
}
```

By using above program i will achive but I want to avoid 300000 / 900000 milliseconds .
Other way

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000, initialDelay = 15 * 60 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 16):

Although little bit late to the party, nevertheless another approach from [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelayString--)

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "PT15M", initialDelayString = "PT2H")
```

Here you can find the [details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html?is-external=true#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) about the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

As per the JavaDocs:

> The time unit is milliseconds by default but can be overridden via
> `timeUnit`.

So you can use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` like this:

```java
// ...
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5, initialDelay = 15, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void scheduleFixedRateWithInitialDelayTask() {
    // ...
}
```

This also works with `fixedDelayString`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, both fixedDelay and initialDelay accepts values in milliseconds.
So you can either go with:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300000, initialDelay = 900000)
```

Or:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5 * 60 * 1000, initialDelay = 15 * 60 * 1000)
```