# How to read value in integer in @Schedule annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-scheduled

The variable used in @Schedule is defined in some other project but to use it in another project
it is read in a class and the passed in @Scheduled in other file.

The variable is defined in the class as:

```
@Value("${cron_frequency_interval_for_logs}")
int cronFrequencyIntervalForLogs;
```

and used as

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${cron_frequency_interval_for_logs}")
```

This works fine but the time it takes is in milliseconds and that too in String type.

What I want and tried is: want the time in integer form and in minutes:

```
@Value("${cron_frequency_interval_for_logs}")
int cronFrequencyIntervalForLogs;
```

This syntax I copied from internet but didn't work for me.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = "#{new Integer('${cron_frequency_interval_for_logs}')}")
```

I want the time to be in minutes as first priority but by referring to the below article I got to know the format would be 5*60*1000 for 5 minutes and in such a case if I can just store 5 in the variable and can do the rest of the calculation as that is going to be repetitive.

Is there any way of doing this?
[Referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749805/how-to-give-minute-in-fixeddelay-initialdelay-in-scheduled-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a property (not a variable) called `run-frequency.minutes` which contains an integer of how frequently you would like a method to execute.  There are three annotation properties that will come in handy:

- `initialDelayString` - Value of how long to wait before the first execution.
- `fixedDelayString` - Value of how long to wait between executions.
- `timeUnit` - The unit to use when evaluating the above two values (MINUTES, SECONDS, etc).

```java
@Scheduled(
    initialDelayString = "${run-frequency.minutes}",
    fixedDelayString = "${run-frequency.minutes}",
    timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES
)
```

On a side note, here is the JavaDoc for that annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html